# How to know if Registered customer was Once a Guest user?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento2.4.6, guest

I need a way to find if the registered user was a guest user in the past. Like Magento 2 stores some kind of flag value which can help me to identify that ***the customer was a guest and later on became a registered customer.***
I'm able to check if the order placed by a customer is a guest or not. But not the info that the customer was once a guest.

Any kind of information is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Its good to use analytics tools or services like Google Analytics or Marketo which can help you track user behavior, including guest users, and provide valuable insights.